# Multiple media entities via Twitter Fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

It doesn't seem like Twitter Fabric for Android/Java supports multiple media entities correctly, at least not without any additional configurations.

I posted a tweet with two pics and it showed as expected in the official and unofficial Twitter clients as two pics ([here's the tweet](https://twitter.com/GPL_/status/560616548734611456)).

When I used my client, which uses Twitter Fabric, the MediaEntity POJO list that gets built contains only one element (one pic). Since I've used Fabric, I've never seen this list grow at all.

Gradle config:

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

API usage:

```
statusesService.userTimeline(userId, userName, MAX_NUM_TWEETS_FETCHED, since, max, false, false, true, true, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() { ... }
```

MediaEntity's fields (note how media's size is only 1 when it seems it should be 2):

[image: MediaEntity fields]

Is this a bug? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: in my case i want to finding media type is either "photo" / "video" but extended_entities is not appear into user-time-line response so what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted support for Fabric and this is apparently a **known** limitation. I asked for any workarounds and ETA for the fix as a response so I guess I'll wait to see what they say.

Comment: Thanks GPL. Anywhere I can follow the information thread to keep myself updated on this?